# Laravel Excel - How to access mapped cells without storing to a model

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I am trying to get the value of some cells in a sheet from an excel file. According to the docs (https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/mapped-cells.html) I need to use `WithMappedCells` and their example code is:

```
public function mapping(): array
    {
        return [
            'name'  => 'B1',
            'email' => 'B2',
        ];
    }
    
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
        ]);
    }
```

Here is my spreadsheet:

[image]

In my import file I have this mapping

```
public function mapping(): array
    {
        return [
            'type_key'  => 'A1',
            'isDraft_key' => 'A2',
            'isPublished_key' => 'A3',
            'type'  => 'B1',
            'isDraft' => 'B2',
            'isPublished' => 'B3',
            
        ];
    }
```

On their github I found this solution: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1836#issuecomment-431808465

```
public function map($row)
    {
        return new Veiling([
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'nummer' => $row['nummer'],
            'info' => $row['info'],
        ]);
    }
```

However, this still tried to add it to a Model. I noticed that it used `$row` So I tried is this:

```
public function map($row): array {
        Log::info($row['type_key']);
        return $row;
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Undefined index: type_key

How do I simple get those values from those specific cells so I can perform some checks on them?

Edit: When I log out just `$row` I get:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'type' => 'isDraft',
    'report.' => 'TRUE',
  ),
  0 =>
  array (
    'type' => 'isPublished',
    'report.' => 'FALSE',
  ),
)
```

As you can see, the data is there but the mapping is not correct. I have checked and I am using :

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMappedCells;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
```

at the top of my file and am making sure my class implements these:

```
Import Implements WithMapping, WithMappedCells {
```